# Java MultipMap single key with multiple value

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, guava, maplist

I working on java application and this is very basic test tool. What we need to do is we have to store multiple value with single key in map list, for example 'key,value,value' that is '1,www.google.com,test', '2,www.gmail.com,Test' and so on. Also, we need to modify value (test) for respective key once the process is completed.

Is there any way of doing this, I have search on Google and could not find it working properly 'https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html'

I would appreciate if you can give me example code with your valued answer.

### Code:

import org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiKeyMap;

public class test {

```
static MultiKeyMap masterLinkList = new MultiKeyMap();
static String fetchUrl, urlStatus, urlMessage;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    masterLinkList.put(1,"www.google.com", "Test");
    masterLinkList.put(2,"www.gmail.com", "Test");

    System.out.println(masterLinkList.get(1));

    masterLinkList.put(2,"www.gmail.com", "Test");

    if(masterLinkList.containsKey(1)&&masterLinkList.containsValue("Test")){
        masterLinkList.put(1,"www.gmail.com", "Passed");
    }
    System.out.println(masterLinkList.get(1));
}
```

}

Thanks,

Comment: Can you paste here the code you have tried?

Comment: That MultiMap works well - what were your problems with it? --- But you can, without much effort, implement a `Map<Integer,List<String>>` or similar. Why haven't you tried that?

Comment: according to my understanding you have to construct the structure somewhat like Map<Object,String> and where your object holds first two values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java core classes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MultiMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        final List<String> valSetOne = new ArrayList<String>();
        valSetOne.add("www.google.com");
        valSetOne.add("test");

        final List<String> valSetTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
        valSetTwo.add("www.gmail.com");
        valSetTwo.add("Test");

        map.put("1", valSetOne);
        map.put("2", valSetTwo);

        final List<String> values = map.get("1");
        System.out.println("Before changing: " + values.get(1));
        values.set(1, "newTest");
        System.out.println("After changing: " + values.get(1));
    }
}
```

How wrote below, you can use Google Guava Collections or Apache Commons Collection too. For example, look link: http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and

Answer (score 1):

Google Guava offers several Multimap implementations which are working well, just have a look at the doc: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

detailed explanation: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap

example:

```
Multimap<String,String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
// Adding some key/value
myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Bannana");
myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Apple");
myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Pear");
myMultimap.put("Vegetables", "Carrot");

// Getting the size
int size = myMultimap.size();
System.out.println(size);  // 4

// Getting values
Collection<string> fruits = myMultimap.get("Fruits");
System.out.println(fruits); // [Bannana, Apple, Pear]

Collection<string> vegetables = myMultimap.get("Vegetables");
System.out.println(vegetables); // [Carrot]

// Iterating over entire Mutlimap
for(String value : myMultimap.values()) {
 System.out.println(value);
}

// Removing a single value
myMultimap.remove("Fruits","Pear");
System.out.println(myMultimap.get("Fruits")); // [Bannana, Pear]

// Remove all values for a key
myMultimap.removeAll("Fruits");
System.out.println(myMultimap.get("Fruits")); // [] (Empty Collection!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way you are describing seems like it could be accomplished by just using a Map structure, where  you have a key mapped to a list of values.

```
Map<String, List<String>> multiValues = new HashMap<>;
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>;
values.add("www.google.com");
values.add("test");
multiValues.put("1", values);
```

But, if you want to change any of the values for that key you will have to do some operations yourself. If you want to find a class that supports multiple values for a single key you, you could use something like [Google Guava's Multimap](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#remove(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 0):

```
logger.info("Logging an INFO-about Directory exists or not.");
        processPropFile();
        String[] urls = prop.getProperty("URL").split(",");
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(urls);
        String[] folder = prop.getProperty("DIRECTORY").split(",");
        List<String> folders = Arrays.asList(folder);
        for (int i = 0; i < folders.size(); i++) {
            String k = folders.get(i);
            File file = new File(k);
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                logger.info("Connected to a Directory!"+folders.get(i));
                if (file.list().length > 0) {
                    logger.info("Directory is not empty!");
                } else {
                    logger.info("Directory is empty!");
                }
            } else {
                logger.error("Invalid Directory!");
                // System.out.println("This is not a directory");
            }
        }
        return null;
```

Answer (score -1):

for `java.util.Map` the key value must be unique, I suggest you implement your own map, something like this:

```
class MyMap implements Map<Object, ArrayList<Object>> {
}
```

and then add a method for putting one element like this:

```
public putOneElement(Object key, Object value) {
this.get(key).put(value);
}
```